# XML with Linq with where

Tags: xml, linq, subquery

I need to find the SectionIndex with the attribute nodeName="Industries" and then get the Attributes (id and nodeName) for each Textpage element in that SectionIndex

```
   <SectionIndex nodeName="Industries">
       <Textpage id="1" nodeName="Aerospace"</Textpage>
       <Textpage id="2" nodeName="Construction"</Textpage>
       <Textpage id="3" nodeName="Engineering"</Textpage>
    </SectionIndex>
    <SectionIndex nodeName="Greetings">
       <Textpage id="1" nodeName="Hello"</Textpage>
       <Textpage id="2" nodeName="GoodBye"</Textpage>
       <Textpage id="3" nodeName="Later"</Textpage>
    </SectionIndex>
```

My query looks like

```
    var queryServices = from s in xmldoc.Root.Descendants("SectionIndex")
                            where s.Attribute("nodeName").Value == "Industries"                                    
                            select new
                            {
                                ServicesKey = s.Element("umbTextpage").Attribute("id").Value ?? "",
                                NodeName = s.Element("umbTextpage").Attribute("nodeName").Value ?? ""
                            };
```

It only returns Aerospace.  Any tips would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var result = xDoc.Descendants("SectionIndex")
            .Where(e => e.Attribute("nodeName").Value == "Industries")
            .SelectMany(e => e.Descendants()
                                 .Select(x => new
                                     {
                                         ServicesKey = x.Attribute("id").Value,
                                         NodeName = x.Attribute("nodeName").Value
                                     }));
```

Comment: This is what worked.  Thanks for the help                         var queryServices = xmldoc.Root.Descendants("SectionIndex")
         .Where(e => e.Attribute("nodeName").Value == "Industries")
         .SelectMany(e => e.Descendants("umbTextpage")
             .Select(x => new
             {
                   ServicesKey = x.Attribute("id").Value,
                   NodeName = x.Attribute("nodeName").Value
             }));

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're cycling through `s` values, each of which is a `SectionIndex`, but you're more interested in the children.

You could rewrite it from the child's point of view:

```
var queryServices =
    from s in xmldoc.Root.Descendants("Textpage")
    where s.Parent.Attribute("nodeName").Value == "Industries"
    select new
        {
            ServicesKey = s.Attribute("id").Value ?? "",
            NodeName = s.Attribute("nodeName").Value ?? ""
        };
```

Alternatively you could split it into two queries: one to get the `SectionIndex` you're interested in, and then a second query on that to extract its children.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help.  Apparently I missed one piece of needed information in the 5000 line config file I am trying to parse.

```
    <root id="-1">
    <SectionIndex id="0" nodeName="Greetings">
         <Textpage id="1" nodeName="Hello"></Textpage>
         <Textpage id="2" nodeName="GoodBye"></Textpage>
         <Textpage id="3" nodeName="Later"></Textpage>
    </SectionIndex>
    <Textpage id="4" nodeName="Services">
        <SectionIndex nodeName="Industries">
             <Textpage id="5" nodeName="Aerospace"></Textpage>
             <Textpage id="6" nodeName="Construction"></Textpage>
             <Textpage id="7" nodeName="Engineering"></Textpage>
        </SectionIndex>
    </Textpage>
    </root>
```

So when I tried to run the suggested query it came back with a null exception error on the where portion do to root not having a nodeName.  Any ideas on how to find the SectionIndex with the attribute nodeName="Industries" and then get the Attributes (id and nodeName) for each Textpage element in that SectionIndex.